# Other than the vignetting, what am I missing by using my Nikkor 35mm f/1.8 DX on an FX camera?

Tags: nikon, full-frame, sensor-size

I recently upgraded from Nikon D3200 (DX) to Nikon D750 (FX). I had the the Nikkor 35mm f/1.8 DX lens - which now I have started using with the D750

I have read everywhere that the DX lenses use just the center portion of the FX sensor.

However, when I use 35mm DX lens with D750, I get a decent picture with some vignetting. A sample screenshot from Lightroom (untouched) is here.

[image: My son and my father]

If I buy a FX 35mm lens, will it give me better field of view and image quality - or should I continue with the current 35mm DX that I have?

Comment: A reference article https://photographylife.com/using-nikon-dx-lenses-on-fx-cameras

Comment: @mattdm Thanks for the edit. It makes more sense now :)

Comment: Just for clarity: you have `Auto DX crop` set to `off`, right?

Comment: Good point. Let me check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you shoot FX wide open at close subjects you will probably like the results.

The Nikkor 35mm f/1.8 DX is rather unique in that it has *almost* FX coverage. Many FX users report acceptable results with it. The field of view will be identical to a 35mm FX lens but there will be strong vignetting which is more noticeable as you stop down or shoot more distant subjects.

Answer (score 1):

Using DX lens means that only a part of its huge FX sensor is actually in use. As for me, this really kills the whole point of owning a full-frame camera, significantly downgrading an image quality.

Strongly advise you to get an FX lens to get a real taste of your camera's capabilities.